# JavaFX: Need help understanding project hierarchy issues

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, manifest

My code has gotten quite large and so I've decided to build a runnable JAR to see how it's done. I probably should've tried sooner because I'm getting 2 different errors related to the project structure, first is the "no main manifest attribute error" when trying to run the JAR from command prompt. Double-clicking the JAR does nothing (Win7). The second issue is related to the FXMLLoader explained lower down.

I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22673644/4731712) to build the JAR, which involved moving all Maven files into the JAR directory. The compiled JAR gave me the manifest error, so I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27662742/4731712) which adds a Maven plugin in my `pom.xml` file. The error might be caused by a wrong naming convention with the line `<mainClass>com.primary.Drag</mainClass>` where `primary` is the package and `Drag` is my Drag.java file (class) which has the `main` method.

Inititally I was using the default package but read that this is not recommended for larger projects, so I put all my files into "primary". Here is my current hierarchy as shown in IntelliJ:

[image: hierachy]

The problem is that ever since I created the "primary" package, I can no longer even compile the program via IntelliJ, let alone build a runnable JAR. This is due by the second error I mentioned, which is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.` on this line within `primary/Drag.java`:

`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("firstlaunch.fxml"));` It used to work with the default package, but not anymore.

I tried replacing `firstlaunch.fxml` with `/primary/firstlaunch.fxml` and `/resources/firstlaunch.fxml` (with and without moving resources into primary package) but no luck.

**3 Related Questions:**

1. Is my project structure incorrect?
2. How do I reference the fxml file from the `primary` package?
3. Is this what I should write in Maven's mainClass tags? `<mainClass>com.primary.Drag</mainClass>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is my project structure incorrect?

Answer:

Your package name should be like com.primary.******

2. How do I reference the fxml file from theprimary package?

Answer:

Always make sure that you are trying to load firstlaunch .xml  from the class which is located in same package where that xml  is kept. Means class which you wrote the loading code and xml  file should be in same package

3. Is this what I should write in Maven's mainClass tags?com.primary.Drag

Answer:

If you package name corrected to com.primary , your main class Drag will correctly added by maven

Comment: Thank you, I renamed the package to com.**** and it worked. I also had to ensure that META-INF folder was in src/main/resources not src/main/java/...