# How to make an executable jar file using IntelliJ from a Selenium/Junit java file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to generate a jar file of my test to use it in JMeter, I am trying this solution [How to make an executable jar file using IntelliJ from a Selenium/TestNG java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648384/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file-using-intellij-from-a-selenium-testng-java-fi) but the problem in on step 4. 
4- Select your main class using the browse button.
When I search for class I can't select mine .java code, how I can do the step 4 possible?

My code

```
public class Jmeter {
    WebDriver driver = null;

    @Test
    public void testLoad() {
      //  Robot robot = new Robot();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("disable-infobars", "ignore-certificate-errors", "start-maximized","use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"));//
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("myurl");
        my commands
    }
}
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

**Solution**

I created a class with the main method to call my test.

```
package Jmeter;
public class JmeterMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jmeter test = new Jmeter();

        test.testLoad();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Thiago their has be at least one java class which contain the main method so if that present then also you can create jar files otherwise you don't

Comment: Thank you @akshaypatil, I created the main method to call my class test.

Comment: if you find this comment is helpful to you then please click on Upside triangle button just above flag on my comment that will be great...^.^ Happy to help..